# función en pascal que te devuelva una matriz

Tags: function, pascal

quiero que la función me devuelva una matriz pero me da error en el tipo de dato

```
program proyecto4;

type Matriz = array[0..7,0..7] of integer;

var
   tableroajedrez:Matriz;
   i,j,k: integer;

       monitor juego8torres;
       export
             imprimirmatriz;
             Llenarmatriz;

                    function funcionrandom(numero:integer):integer;
                             var result:integer;
                             begin
                                  repeat
                                        result:= random(numero);
                                  until(result<>0);
                                  funcionrandom:=result;
                             end;

                    function validarposicion(fila,columna:integer;tab:Matriz):Boolean;
                    begin
                         if(tab[fila][columna] <> 1) then
                            begin
                                 validarposicion:=True;
                            end
                         else
                            begin
                                 validarposicion:=False;
                            end
                    end;



                    function Llenarmatriz(tablero:Matriz):Matriz;
                             var i,j,k:integer;
                    begin
                         for i:=0 to 7 do
                             begin
                                  for j:=0 to 7 do
                                      begin
                                           tablero[i,j]:=0;
                                      end;
                             end;
                         for k:=0 to 7 do
                             begin
                                  i:= funcionrandom(7);
                                  j:= random(7);
                                  if validarposicion(i,j,tablero) then
                                       begin
                                            tablero[i,j]:=1;
                                       end
                             end;
                        Llenarmatriz:=tablero;
                    end;

                   procedure imprimirmatriz(i,j:integer; tab:Matriz);
                   begin
                        for i:=0 to 7 do
                             begin
                                  for j:=0 to 7 do
                                      begin
                                           write(tab[i,j]);
                                           write(' ');
                                      end;
                                  writeln(' ');
                             end;
                   end;
    var resultado:Matriz;
    begin  (* monitor body *)
        resultado:=juego8torres.Llenarmatriz(tableroajedrez);
        juego8torres.imprimirmatriz(0,0,resultado);
    end;
begin

end.
```

el error de tipo de dato me da justo aquí
`function llenarmatriz(Tablero:Matriz): Matriz;`

Comment: @gbianchi en la función, me dice error de tipo

Comment: function llenarmatriz(Tablero:Matriz): Matriz; aquí mismo @gbianchi

Comment: ya la edite  @gbianchi

Comment: te puse todo el codigo @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

No sé que compilador estás utilizando, pero los compiladores antiguos de Pascal no soportaban utilizar tipos arreglo como resultado de las funciones.

Los compiladores modernos, si que lo soportan. He probado compilar tu código (luego de un par de adaptaciones, con Delphi, y compila sin problemas).

Lo que se solía hacer en tiempos pasados, era utilizar procedimientos con parámetros variables para *pasar* matrices.

Podrías, por ejemplo, adaptar tu código de esta manera:

```
procedure Llenarmatriz(var Result:Matriz);
var
  I, J, K:integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 7 do
    for J := 0 to 7 do
      Result[I, J] := 0;
  for k:= 0 to 7 do
  begin
    I := funcionrandom(7);
    J := random(7);
    if validarposicion(i, j, Result) then
      Result[i,j] := 1;
  end;
end;
```

Y luego el sitio de la llamada:

```
var 
  Resultado: Matriz;
begin  
  juego8torres.Llenarmatriz(Resultado);
  ...
```